# horizontally center flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to horizontally center `.div2` without position `absolute/fixed` like this image?

[image]

div3 can change width

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.test {
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
}

.test .div1 {
  
}

.test .div2 {
  margin:0 auto;
background:red;
}

.test .div3 {
  margin:0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="div1">Left options</div>
  <div class="div2">Center div</div>
  <div class="div3">Username: test (string can change)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: See Box #71, Solution #2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 0):

give display flex to parent element. then `justify-contents` aligns child on main axis and `align-items' align child vertically. 
Get more details https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="div1">Left options</div>
  <div class="div2">Center div</div>
  <div class="div3">Username: test (string can change)</div>
</div>
<style>
.test{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give all the divs 33.3333% width

```css
.test {
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
}

.test .div1 {
  width:33.3333%;
}

.test .div2 {
  margin:0 auto;
background:red;
  width:33.3333%;
}

.test .div3 {
  margin:0 0 0 auto;
    width:33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="div1">Left options</div>
    <div class="div2">Center div</div>
    <div class="div3">Username: test (string can change)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` style property like below.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.test {
  background: green;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
}

.test div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>Left options</div>
  <div>Center div</div>
  <div>Username: test (string can change)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:left;` to all `div`s within `.test` would do the trick.

```
.test>div{float:left;}
```

If you would like the `div`s to take up full width, then give it the width of `width:33.3333%;` (no. of `divs` / 100)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6onazzuu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming that you want the div2 to keep it's size, and div1 and div3 elements to grow until they touch it. Set for those elements a flex-basis of 0:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.test {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
.test .div2 {
  background: red;
}
.test .div1,
.test .div3 {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.div3 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="div1">Left options</div>
  <div class="div2">Center div</div>
  <div class="div3">Username: test (string can change)</div>
</div>
```